# gcp rest call to get machine types supported for different gpu types

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, call

I am trying to use this rest call to get machine types and accelerators supported for it :[https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{}/zones/{}/machineTypes](https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%7B%7D/zones/%7B%7D/machineTypes).
While i get the accelerators information for a2 and g2, the info is not available for n1 machine type...

I tried the accelerator types call and machine types rest call..Is there any other gcp rest call which can list supported machine types for any gpu type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API or CLI command to list GPUs at this time.

Note: only the N1, A2, and G2 VMs support GPUs. That should simplify your search for GPU machine types that support GPU attachments.

I use this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus) to look up GPU details.

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/create-gpu-vm-general-purpose) details the GPUs supported for the N1 family.

Most regions support a limited selection of GPUs. Consult this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones) for more details.

At this time, it takes research to know if a machine type supports a GPU type in the desired region/zone. For example, the zone `us-west1-c` does not support any GPUs.